# Files synced by Synk Pro have wrong owner on both synchronized Macs – how can I fix it?

Tags: macos, data-synchronization, command-line, permission

I sync some folders within my Home folder between two Macs (running Lion and Mountain Lion) using [Synk Pro](http://decimus.net/Synk/SynkPro), a commercial live file sync application. I have the same account name on both computers.

After syncing, some of my files on both computers are read-only, and they also aren't owned by me, but by the *macports* account – why?

[image: Capture of the "Sharing & Permissions" section of a "Get Info" window, showing "macports" as the owner]

To be able to modify files, I've used Get Info to change permissions of some files to read/write for 'everyone', and I used the app [Permissions Reset](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/31741/permissions-reset) to reset permissions back to original, but it doesn't change the permissions of sub-folders/files, and I have a huge file tree, so doing this manually is practically impossible. And Disk Utility does nothing to user data.

How can I fix this?

--
Added info:

As suggested, I ran the commands `id -u` and `id -u macports` on both computers. The result is that on the MacBook Pro, my account has uid 501 and *macports* has uid 502, and on the iMac it's the other way around.

Comment: @ArneStenström just edited my question. I don't get you second question, but not all my files is that way, but I can't track why anymore, because before I start to sync files, I copied some manually using AFP and using external HDD, I'm dealing with that situation for months, I really don't know when this started, I just modifying permissions to 'everyone' to w/r when I try to modify a file and I get a error. I know I messed everything even more.

Comment: OH you're a genius! MPB `id -u vitim 501` `id -u macports 502` on iMac `id -u vitim 502` `id -u macports 501`

Comment: I executed `sudo chown -R /Users/vitim/` on both computers and it fixed my files. I changed the Ownership option to Ignore, hopefully this will prevent my files turning ownership to `macports`. Please append your comment to your answer, so I can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @ArneStenström - hmm let me think that over. Lets [chat] to see what's best for the site.

Comment: thanks for editing, hopefully this will help someone else.

Comment: I know after reading the begining of the @ArneStenström answer that read-only is caused by not being the owner, but I think that worth mentioning "read-only" in the title to help other people finding the question, also the title suggested by Arne is more likely to be find by someone with the same problem. IMHO

Comment: If the OP here likes @ArneStenström 's edit - please either of you place that in the title. I still like my version better, but I'll defer to any two people having a preference over my suggestion. It was meant to help get votes / be searchable - so everyone can try searching with terms they like and see that the engine yields this question whether or not the title has read-only in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The files appearing read-only to you is probably only because you are currently not their owner.
    What's likely happening is that the synced files retain the numeric owner-id from the source machine, and since that numeric *uid* in this particular case corresponds to the account *macports* on the target machine (in both transfer directions), *macports* has become the owner.

To verify that your account on each computer has the same numeric uid as the *macports* account has on the other machine, type the commands `id -u` and `id -u macports` in the Terminal in your account on both computers.

#### Fixing the cause of the problem

When information was submitted that the syncing is done using Synk Pro, I had [a look at the Synk Pro web site](http://decimus.net/Synk/SynkPro#slider) and the app, and in the 'Advanced' settings I noticed the "**Ownership:**" option, which by default is set to "Copy If Possible".
    Since it looks like Synk Pro transfers files' numeric uid, and there's no option for mapping this uid to another uid/account on the target computer, the way to make synced files be owned by you is to change the "Ownership:" setting to "**Ignore**".

[image: screen capture of Synk Pro's advanced "Ownership" option set to "Ignore"]

#### Fixing the files

To fix the permission problem for the already synced files, you only need to change the owner of the files to your own account. Since (in this case) all of your synced folders are within your Home folder /Users/*youraccount*, you can do this with the following command in the Terminal when logged in to an administrator account (you'll have to give sudo the password of the admin account):

```
sudo chown -R youraccount /Users/youraccount
```

using the actual account name (also known as *short user name*) of your own account in place of *youraccount*. The account name is the same as the name of your account's Home folder in the /Users folder.
    This will change all files and folders within the folder /Users/*youraccount* to be owned by *youraccount* (-R is for recursive), which should give you write-access to all of your files.

Since you earlier gave write-permission to 'everyone' for some files to be able to modify them, you may want to remove those permissions. This command:

```
sudo chmod -R u+w,go-w /Users/youraccount
```

ensures that the owner of your files, and no-one else, has write permission on them.

Type `man chown` and `man chmod` for more info about these commands.

---

#### Advice against using Finder to fix a folder's permissions

(*I will update the below later*)

Note: It is possible to change ownership and permissions of all files and folders in a folder tree using the **Finder**, by use of the controls at the very bottom of the *Sharing & Permissions* section of a Get Info window as shown in the picture in the question. One **problem** with this is that an account's home folder, and the standard subfolders therein, such as Library, Documents, Public and so forth, have special permissions (by use of ACLs) preventing them from being deleted among other things, and you **don't** want these special permissions to be removed or propagated to other folders and even files, so you should **not** use this unless you know very well what you are doing.

Comment: The next time I edit this answer, I will mention more directly in the lead paragraph that Vitim's accounts on the two Macs have different uid. Seems like it was too obvious to mention ...

Answer (score 1):

There is a drag-and-drop freeware app with a GUI that can do this for you if you don't want to use Terminal commands. It is called [BatChmod](http://www.lagentesoft.com/batchmod/).

Be very careful in using it, or any other method; changing the privileges of a whole directory tree of files at once can have unintended consequences.

Answer (score -2):

You can easily do to this in the shell (terminal) like on Linux using `chmod`

When using `chmod`, you have the three letters `u`, `g`, `o` (user, group, other) for defining the instance to which you want to give the permission. And the three letters `r`, `w`, `x` (read, write, execute) to define the kind of permission.

If you want to give all the read and execute permission, you would use
`chmod ugo +rx target`. Similarly, you can take away permissions using `-` instead of `+`

Comment: How do I apply chmod to the entire directory tree? And change permissions but how I change the owner back to my user?

Comment: use `chmod -R` for the directory tree and `chown user1 user2` to change ownership.

Comment: Btw, why is my answer voted down? I think it works perfectly fine!